# Leave Darlington inputs unconnected

Tags: darlington, floating-pin

I'm designing a relay-driver board with 15 double throw relays.

I'm using shift registers to save IO-pins on the CPU. The shift registers feed into darlington ST ULN2003A transistor arrays: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf .

During bootup, I'm thinking about arranging so that output-enable on the shift registers is disabled.

This should be safe, right? There's no way a darlington transistor will start conducting when the base is floating? With MOSFET I know it wouldn't really be stable, since the MOSFET gate could keep a charge for a long time. But it should be safe with bipolar transistors, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the leakage current of the shift register. It can definitly be high enough to turn a darlington switch on. You should consider pulling the base down.

Also if you need fast switching though the Miller Effect can be a problem. A pull-down at the base would help with this too.

As your specific transistor already includes a pull-down path, you will most likely be fine though.

Comment: Ah, I missed that! The transistor I've chosen has a 13k internal pull-down. No problem then. I need a switching speed of about 10 ms, and I can't imagine that would be a problem?

Comment: @avl_sweden I guess 10 ms is slow enough.